# Making a loop start over and go back to the starting color when it is done going through each step

Tags: javascript

I am currently coding a process section where with each arrow click, it moves to a new process step and a little icon man moves along and the blocks under him change color as you move through. My issue is that I need the color blocks to go back to the original color once all the process items are through and the icon man is back at the beginning. I also need to be able to click through the arrows back and forth and have the block colors change accordingly. This is probably a simple fix but I am new to Javascript so any help would be appreciated!

Another small thing I need help with is changing the icon on the last block. When I try and do this, it makes everything disappear.

Here is a link to my code: https://codepen.io/jesssherry/pen/voYwmK

This is my JS code:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  var lastIcon = document.getElementsByClassName("last");

  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }

  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    if (slideIndex >= 1) {
      dots[slideIndex-1].classList.add("visitedred");
    }
  }

  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Comment: It's great that you're learning how to program JavaScript but try and keep your title focused on explaining the problem. The problem is not that you're learning, but something to do with your code. I've also formatted your code with consistent indentation so it's easier to read, and also to make potential syntax errors more obvious.

Comment: One thing to note: The index of the final slide is not `slides.length` but `slides.length-1`. The index of the first slide is `0`, not `1`. You're trying to emulate a 1-indexed array in here which could be part of the problem. It's best to use 0-indexed and just roll with it.

Comment: Hi @tadman thanks for the reply! I changed it to be 0-indexed and am still seeing issues with the last slide. Here's a link to the update codepen if you wouldn't mind taking a look: https://codepen.io/jesssherry/pen/QevyBE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you for loop:

```
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    if (slideIndex >= 1) {
      dots[slideIndex-1].classList.add("visitedred");
    }
  }
```

You need to add to the condition this line:

```
dots[slideIndex].classList.remove("visitedred");
```

Working snippet:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

  function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
  }

  function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
  }

  function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    var lastIcon = document.getElementsByClassName("last");

    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        if (slideIndex >= 1) {
          dots[slideIndex-1].classList.add("visitedred");
          dots[slideIndex].classList.remove("visitedred");
        }
        
      }

    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";


  }
```

```css
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
}

.txt-c {
  text-align: center;
}


/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top:50px;
}

/* Slides */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: inherit;
  /*top: 15%;*/
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #f9464b !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  position: inherit;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: white;
}
.controllers {
  text-align:center;
}
/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */
.dot-container {

  padding: 20px;

}
.dot-arrows {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 75px;
  width: 35px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #5bbcc9;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */
.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #f9464b;
}
.active:before {
  content: "\f554";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  position:absolute;
  top:-25px;
  background-color:transparent !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:40px;
  color:#5bbcc9;
}
.hoorayman:before{
  content: "\f1ae";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  position:absolute;
  top:-25px;
  background-color:transparent !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:40px;
  color:#5bbcc9;
}
.dot-container .dot:before {
 background-color: #f9464b;
}
/* Add a background color to visited dots */
.visitedred {
  background-color: #f9464b;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/11617bbe1a.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row txt-c">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h1>Process</h1>
      <p>
        We work in 12-week cycles so that we can easily reevaluate and pivot our strategy, methods, and people as needed.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container container">
<div class="row">

  <div class="dot-arrows">

    <!-- Dots/bullets/indicators -->
    <div class="dot-container">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(7)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(8)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(9)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(10)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(11)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(12)"></span>
      <span class="dot last" onclick="currentSlide(13)"></span>

    </div>

    <!-- Next/prev buttons -->
    <div class="controllers">
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)"><i class="fal fa-arrow-left fa-2x"></i></a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)"><i class="fal fa-arrow-right fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <!-- Full-width slides/quotes -->
  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>PRE-LAUNCH</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 1</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 2</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 3</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 4</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 5</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 6</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 7</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 8</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 9</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 10</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 11</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 12</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>
```

Nice idea!

---

EDIT:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
  showSlides(slideIndex);

  function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
  }

  function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
  }

  function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    var lastIcon = document.getElementsByClassName("last");

    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
      if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
      for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        if (slideIndex > 1 && slideIndex < 13) {
          dots[slideIndex-1].classList.add("visitedred");
          dots[slideIndex].classList.remove("visitedred");
        }
        if (slideIndex === 13) {
          dots[12].classList.remove("active");
          dots[12].classList.add("hoorayman");
        }
        if (slideIndex === 1) {
          dots[12].classList.remove("hoorayman");
          dots[i].classList.remove("visitedred");
          dots[0].classList.add("visitedred");
        }
      }

    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  }
```

```css
.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
}

.txt-c {
  text-align: center;
}


/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-top:50px;
}

/* Slides */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: inherit;
  /*top: 15%;*/
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -30px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: #f9464b !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  position: inherit;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  color: white;
}
.controllers {
  text-align:center;
}
/* The dot/bullet/indicator container */
.dot-container {

  padding: 20px;

}
.dot-arrows {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 75px;
  width: 35px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #5bbcc9;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

/* Add a background color to the active dot/circle */
.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #f9464b;
}
.active:before {
  content: "\f554";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  position:absolute;
  top:-25px;
  background-color:transparent !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:40px;
  color:#5bbcc9;
}
.hoorayman:before{
  content: "\f1ae";
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro";
  position:absolute;
  top:-25px;
  background-color:transparent !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-size:40px;
  color:#5bbcc9;
}
.dot-container .dot:before {
 background-color: #f9464b;
}
/* Add a background color to visited dots */
.visitedred {
  background-color: #f9464b;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/11617bbe1a.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row txt-c">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h1>Process</h1>
      <p>
        We work in 12-week cycles so that we can easily reevaluate and pivot our strategy, methods, and people as needed.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Slideshow container -->
<div class="slideshow-container container">
<div class="row">

  <div class="dot-arrows">

    <!-- Dots/bullets/indicators -->
    <div class="dot-container">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(0)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(6)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(7)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(8)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(9)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(10)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(11)"></span>
      <span class="dot last" onclick="currentSlide(12)"></span>
      

    </div>

    <!-- Next/prev buttons -->
    <div class="controllers">
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)"><i class="fal fa-arrow-left fa-2x"></i></a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)"><i class="fal fa-arrow-right fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <!-- Full-width slides/quotes -->
  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>PRE-LAUNCH</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 1</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 2</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 3</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 4</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 5</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 6</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 7</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 8</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 9</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 10</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 11</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides">
    <h2>WEEK 12</h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for your response. I am receiving an error when I add that code. On the last slide the icon does not move and this error appears: {
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 302,
  "colno": 28
}

Comment: Hi @A.Meshu I see what you mean. I had <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> to 13 - so I changed to start with 0 and go to 12. I am still experiencing the same issue. Do you have any ideas for how I can resolve this?

Comment: I am still having trouble resolving this! I edited my codepen as you can see here: https://codepen.io/jesssherry/pen/vomLBr the last step does not show up and the changed icon shows up prematurely

Comment: @JSherry please check my update. I change a little the conditions and add another one. Hope that is what you wanted...

Comment: Thank you so much!! I really appreciate all of your help